# Kali Linux - Bluetooth HCI error don't let live system boot

Tags: linux-kernel, kali-linux, live-usb, bluetooth

**Hello community** i have a bootable USB Drive (usb2.0) with [Kali Linux 2017.1 x86](http://old.kali.org/kali-images/kali-2017.1/kali-linux-2017.1-i386.iso) on it, i used rufus for doing this couple years ago, i was using Kali Live system to test some of my java programs with my older laptop. now i changed my laptop but i cannot boot the live system on it, it keeps giving the same error everytime. the error is:

```
[   OK    ] Reached target Graphical Interface.
            Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[   OK    ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[22.524390] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[22.531939] r8169 0000:02:00.0: frimware: direct-loading frimware rtl_nic/rt18168h-2.fw
[22.551877] r8169 0000:02:00.0: eth0: link down
[22.552677] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[22.701099] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: las cmd=0x000f0000
[30.377063] bluetooth: hci0: download fw command failed (-110)
```

and when it reachs the `bluetooth HCI` line,the screen is flashes for about 5 minute. the screen flash stops after showing that the `kernel`is suspending:

```
[152.485734] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: evicting buffers...
[152.486839] nonveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: waiting for kernel channels to go idle...
[152.487983] nonveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending client object tree...
[152.492557] nonveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: suspending kernel object tree...
```

finally it freeze on these line and not doing anything further, i can also access a terminal `alt+f4`! i don't know what causing the problem really, my WLAN model is **Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe** and it runs on latest version, and my BIOS as well. i found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/404266/cannot-wake-up-from-suspend?answertab=votes#tab-top) while searching for the cause of suspending kernel, and followed the steps, but it wasn't change anything. and i turned off the **secure boot** too, the only thing that makes system to boot is to choose the `live system (i386 failsafe)` which i don't know so much about it.

USB Drive info: USB 2.0 SanDisk, 32GB, MBR, FAT32.

what is the causing this problem?

thank you all.

PS: i changed the kali linux version for kali linux 2020.1 but same thing happened, i also have to mention that both 2017 and 2020 versions runs well on my older laptop and on VMware too.

Comment: See http://kali.org/blog and http://forums.kali.org and if neither answer your questions, the Kali IRC channel is #kali-linux, and can be found on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: i checked forums.kali.org, apparently i didn't find a way to "post questions", i didn't even get the confirmation email to continue setup my account! for the other one (irc.freenode.net) feels pretty weird,there is no login/sign-in button. I'm not sure if i used it wrong, but neither of these solution seem to work for me, maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) community is the best place to go, i used to use stackexchange communities, Thank you BTW :)

Comment: actually i received the verification email after about 24 hours, my account is done and as always it took me to the homepage(**kali forums**) but it's same screen, i mean i do see other members posts! but  no **post** button or something indicate to **asking** or **posting question**. anyway i think this site quite hard for me to use, i mean it have an old UI and not too user-friendly IMO. thank you again =)